# If $A<C$ is finite must $A<B,B<C$ be finite

Tags: commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Let $A<B<C$ be a tower of commutative rings with identity. If $C$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module, must we have the following:

1) $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module.

2) $C$ is finitely generated as an $B$-module. (This is trivial already as noted by user26857.)

Do 1), 2) have to hold if at least we restrict ourselves to integral domains?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of a ring extension? What does $A < B$ mean?

Comment: @k.stm  that $A$ is a subring of $B$, same as field extensions

Comment: Okay, if by $A < B$ you simply meant there is a ring morphism $A → B$, then obviously 1) wouldn’t be necessarily true as well.

Comment: @k.stm I meant subring. There is no need to speak about morphisms. I believe my question has a precise meaning when formulated using subrings

Comment: For 1) one can use a similar counter-example to the linked one by setting e.g. $C=A[Y]/(Y^2-X_1)$.